# Validating any string with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate any string that contains çÇöÖİşŞüÜğĞ chars and starting at least 5 chars.String to validate can contain spaces.RegEx must validate like "asd Çğ   ğT i" for example.

Any reply will helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Wow I completely don't know what "yiyle" means, and I'm usually pretty good at guessing.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to understand what you want that regex to do. Maybe you could clarify your question a little bit?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as accepted (check the tick under the answer you think is the best)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use escape sequences of the form

```
\uXXXX
```

where each "X" can be any hex digit.  Thus:

```
\u0020
```

is the same as a plain space character, and

```
\u0041
```

is upper-case "A".  Thus you can encode the Unicode values for the characters you're interested in and then include them in a regex character class. To make sure the string is at least five characters long, you can use a *quantifier* in the regex.

You'll end up with something like:

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z\u00nn\u00nn\u00nn]{5,}$/;
```

where those "00nn" things would be the appropriate values. As to exactly what those values are, you should be able to find them on a reference site [like this one](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html) or [maybe this one](http://www.unicode.org/charts/). For example I think that "Ö" is `\u00D6`. (Some of your characters are in the Unicode Latin-1 Supplement, while others are in Latin Extended A.)